# Expose ports on Azure VMRole

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-vm-role

Can we expose ports on a Azure VMRole after we have published the project onto Azure?
Probably using Azure Powershell cmdlets or some other way.

At present, I am deleting the VMRole and adding new endpoints on my project (Visual Studio Azure Project) and re-publish it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the answer is no for cloud apps. (VM Role is one type of role for a cloud app.) Endpoints have to be declared before publishing.

Comment: I haven't found any way of doing it yet, hence your's seems to be the answer we are looking for. Hopefully if someone finds a trick, will comment here. Cheers.